# ElasticSearch Java Client missing documents

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've setup the elasticsearch client on my Java application, I used a for loop and tried to insert documents into my index, each for loop will execute 100k times and I have 4 for loops at the time, I tried Run and Debug mode on the code but my result of total hits count are not 400k when executing the search API with `matchAllQuery`, I add more search requests at a time but all get back less than 400k count. What caused my document insertion failure?

**EDIT 1:**
I already set the search size to 400k

**EDIT 2:**
This is my for loop sample and search API sample

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
                client.prepareIndex("fb", "post", String.valueOf(i)).setTimeout(new TimeValue(6000))
                .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                            .startObject()
                                .field("content", "freeze on the intake of foreign workers including the "
                                        + "1.5 million from Bangladesh has been met with scepticism by kuala lumpur"
                                        + "a Bangladesh official, the Dhaka Tribune reported quoted the acting secretary of Bangladesh")
                            .endObject()
                          ).execute();
            }


for(int i = 100000; i < 200000; i++){
                client.prepareIndex("fb", "post", String.valueOf(i)).setTimeout(new TimeValue(6000))
                .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                            .startObject()
                                .field("content", "freeze on the intake of foreign workers including the "
                                        + "1.5 million from Bangladesh has been met with scepticism by kuala lumpur"
                                        + "a Bangladesh official, the Dhaka Tribune reported quoted the acting secretary of Bangladesh")
                            .endObject()
                          ).execute();
            }

SearchResponse response3 = client.prepareSearch("fb")
                    .setTypes("post")
                    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                    .setScroll(new TimeValue(120000))
                    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("content", "kuala"))
                    .setSize(400000)
                    .execute()
                    .actionGet();
```

All of them returning the same count

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also, what's the number of records that you have on your `elastic` index?

Comment: I updated my question and I have 192452 documents count

Comment: Have you tried to query your `elastic` database directly, using `elastic`'s query API on your browser?